# a class similar to android.graphics.Canvas, but useable with GLSurfaceView.Renderer / opengles.GL10

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

According to android dev docs, if I made a custom view I could easily draw lines at arbitrary angles by overriding `onDraw(Canvas canvas)`, and calling `canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint)`.

However, I am now tasked with modifying an application that instead creates a subclass of `GLSurfaceView`, and an implementer of `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`, in which drawing is performed in an override of `onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)`.

So, I don't have an `android.graphics.Canvas` object. Instead, I have a `javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10` object.

In theory I could attempt to obtain the canvas object via

```
SurfaceHolder holder = ..my surface view..
Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
...
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

But I suspect that doing that either won't work at all, or is unreliable, or at least runs against the benefit of using GLSurfaceView, which manages the display, and presumably calls the renderer at an appropriate time to do some rendering (so the last thing I would want to do is attempt to lock something -- sounds like that would deadlock).

I did attempt the above, and got an exception which I could post here, but I'm thinking that is simply not what I should be attempting, so won't go down that road unless appropriate.

So, instead of a canvas, with its convenient high level API for various 2D drawing operations, I have a lower-level GL10 class.

For my purposes, the 2D drawing operations of Canvas were perfect.

Is there functionality compatible with `GL10` class, similar to `android.graphics.Canvas`, perhaps via a third-party library?

Or is there a correct way to use the Canvas class from a GLSurfaceView.Renderer?

---

Here is a discussion that sounds like what I have in mind, but rather than roll my own, I am looking for some existing source code:  http://basic4gl.wikispaces.com/2D+Drawing+in+OpenGL

---

That is, I am interested in a higher-level interface, that handles those steps for me.

So the interface might be something like:

```
HypotheticalLibrary.Drawing2D.drawLine(gl, startX, startY, endX, endY, paint);
```

where paint is some type of object that describes how to draw the line.  `x` and `y` would be in pixels of the screen region that was assigned to `gl` when the `GLSurfaceView` was set up. Or they might be screen independent, perhaps by having the drawable region represented by `(0..1)` in x and y.

Comment: You will have to look for a third-party library as this functionality isn't built directly into Android. You might want to look at libgdx. Note that libgdx won't use a `SurfaceView` directly. It provides it's own API.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice would you describe libgdx as an **alternative** to SurfaceView, for obtaining high-performance rendering?

Comment: Yes, it is an alternative to `SurfaceView` and low-level OpenGL programming. I don't know about the performance in comparison.

Comment: A tutorial with a claim that LibGDX "is the most optimized OpenGL framework/wrapper you will find anywhere".  http://www.rengelbert.com/tutorial.php?id=175  Fortunately it isn't  important to me whether it is **the** best; having a solution with reasonable performance, in popular use, and having commands such as drawLine (which I see), is quite sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are required to use `GLSurfaceView` you are stuck with the low-level routines it provides through the `GL10` or `GL20` objects. These require a thorough understanding of the OpenGL engine.

In 1.0, you will use the `glBegin()`, `glEnd()` and the `glVertex()` family of functions. In 2.0, you will use shaders and the GL Shader Language.

LibGDX is a popular library that acts as a wrapper for OpenGL. However, it has its own API and doesn't use `GLSurfaceView`. Some research might find other libraries that provide a higher level interface for you to use with `GLSurfaceView`, but I am unaware of any. (Note that I am very, very new to OpenGL programming on Android.)

Comment: I could possibly stop using GLSurfaceView, once I know enough about an alternative solution. Interestingly I do see in libgdx a mention of GLSurfaceView:  https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/surfaceview/GLSurfaceView20.java  Don't know yet whether that means they have a way to do **all** their drawing into a GLSurfaceView, or whether it is there for some more limited purpose.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve It's not surprising that LibGDX uses `GLSurfaceView` internally since it is a wrapper for OpenGL (and several other libraries). However, when you **use** libgdx, you will not interact with a `GLSurfaceView` directly.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. It will be interesting to see if I can also access the GLSurfaceView with other code, without interfering with LibGDX.  For example, the application that I am modifying already contains an approach to rendering text as sprites, using a font that has been pre-rendered into a texture buffer.  I either have to make it so that code can continue to work, or replace it by something in LibGDX.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative for java opengles.GL10 programming: [cocos2d-android](https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/).

I mention this alternative, because it does work directly with a `GL10` object. E.g. `drawLine(GL10 gl, CCPoint origin, CCPoint destination)`.

> NOTE: this is different than
>   [Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Cocos2d-x), which is written
>   in C++. I feel it is simpler to stick with java.

It contains a java class which draws simple 2D shapes. [Primitives.java](https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/source/browse/trunk/src/org/cocos2d/opengl/Primitives.java)

I have not examined the other classes yet, to see if any special set-up is required for the 2D shapes to render properly.

If import cocos2d-android project into Android Studio, and launch it to a device, a list of demos is seen. Pick "DrawPrimitivesTest" to see this class in action. LineWidth and color are set before calling drawLine: `gl.glLinewidth(5.0f);  gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);`.

In that test code, we see that anti-aliasing is done by `gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LINE_SMOOTH);` Unfortunately anti-aliasing only works with 1-pixel-thick lines, on my moto g.

The code makes no attempt to compensate for the limitations of gl.glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, ..) when using a thick line. Specifically, each segment visually is an independent rectangle, which means that adjacent lines at different angles will have a small triangular gap on one side; see the large green circle in the demo. (I tried changing the number of lines, used to approximate the circle, to 200. There were still a few gaps visible.)

Bottom line: GL_LINE_STRIP (which this library uses) is best used for thin lines.